# Locale Support for Canadian Short Codes

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, locale

According to the following [Marketing Cloud Valid Locales Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_data_extension_locales.htm&type=5), there seems to be no support for the english Canadian locale, only for the french Canadian.

**Unsupported Locale:**

> English (Canada) 'en-ca'

Does anyone know if this is supported or will the english (United States) locale suffice?

Comment: I think that you will need to open a ticket to Support directly. Maybe you can use another locale instead.

Answer (score 0):

`EN` should probably suffice, but the documentation you linked does mention `CA` as a separate option.

You can easily test what is accepted in Mobile Connect when you click the dropdown next to the `Add Contacts` button and select `Add Manually`.

Comment: Sorry, the locale field on a manual add does not accept the 5 letter ISO locale format, it takes a 2 character length format.

Answer (score 0):

The **ca** locale is English by default the **fr-ca** option is available to support the secondary language.

Comment: When I look at standard iso locale codes on different sites, they all slightly vary, (ie. ca is equal to Catalan so I am not confident this relates to Canada. Canada should have 2 locales, either english or french.